# Code works on Codepen, but not JSFiddle or HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I have a banner that I want to blur as you scroll, and I found a code. I edited it, and it looks beautiful in Codepen, but it doesn't work in JSFiddle or on my HTML page. I'll post the links for each of them below.
I'm probably just doing something wrong, but help would really be appreciated.

Codepen (working): http://codepen.io/theinvadingdingo/pen/MwmwrM
JSFiddle (not working): https://jsfiddle.net/mn7p1451/

If you need it, here are the codes I'm using for HTML, CSS, and Javascript:

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="content">
        <hgroup>
             <h1>Wolf Valley</h1>
        </hgroup>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</header>
<div class="site"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import"bourbon";
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
 html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
html {
    font: 1em/1.5"Lato", sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
body {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
header {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(http://s6.postimg.org/j8n8hawrl/Flower.png) center no-repeat;
    /* Image Credit: Unsplash.me */
    background-size: cover;
    .content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    h1, h2 {
        margin: 0;
    }
    h2 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin-top: -.5em;
    }
    hgroup {
        @include transform(translate(-50%, -50%));
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        color: #fff;
        border: 5px solid #fff;
        padding: .5em 3em;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: url(http://s6.postimg.org/6sqink3fl/Flower_Blur.png) center no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
.site {
    padding: 20em 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #efefef;
    font-size: .8em;
    color: #444;
    a {
        color: #666;
        text-decoration: none;
        &:hover {
            color: #222;
        }
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
/**
 * Cache
 */
var $content = $('header .content'),
    $blur = $('header .overlay'),
    wHeight = $(window).height();

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    wHeight = $(window).height();
});

/**
 * requestAnimationFrame Shim 
 */
window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

/**
 * Scroller
 */
function Scroller() {
    this.latestKnownScrollY = 0;
    this.ticking = false;
}

Scroller.prototype = {
    /**
     * Initialize
     */
    init: function () {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this), false);
    },

    /**
     * Capture Scroll
     */
    onScroll: function () {
        this.latestKnownScrollY = window.scrollY;
        this.requestTick();
    },

    /**
     * Request a Tick
     */
    requestTick: function () {
        if (!this.ticking) {
            window.requestAnimFrame(this.update.bind(this));
        }
        this.ticking = true;
    },

    /**
     * Update.
     */
    update: function () {
        var currentScrollY = this.latestKnownScrollY;
        this.ticking = false;

        /**
         * Do The Dirty Work Here
         */
        var slowScroll = currentScrollY / 4,
            blurScroll = currentScrollY * 2;

        $content.css({
            'transform': 'translateY(-' + slowScroll + 'px)',
                '-moz-transform': 'translateY(-' + slowScroll + 'px)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(-' + slowScroll + 'px)'
        });

        $blur.css({
            'opacity': blurScroll / wHeight
        });
    }
};

/**
 * Attach!
 */
var scroller = new Scroller();
scroller.init();
```

Comment: You didn't include jQuery in the fiddle.

Comment: And you're using SCSS in the codepen but not in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn 't close the header section after writing css ...See below code. Please check

```
header {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(http://s6.postimg.org/j8n8hawrl/Flower.png) center no-repeat;
    /* Image Credit: Unsplash.me */
    background-size: cover;

}//NOT CLOSED IN JSFIDDLE
    .content {
```

Comment: I completely missed that! Weird because it worked before I copy/pasted... Anyway, thanks! (The JS still doesn't work, but I'm figuring it out.)

Comment: I think in console showing $ not defined. I think js is not called. Can you share the url?

Comment: If you dont mind can you please share the url for checking the issue?

Comment: I got it all figured out! I spent a few hours last night working out the kinks. Anywho, here is the finished product if you'd like to see: http://wolfvalley.freeforums.net

Answer (score 3):

Look at your JavaScript console. Seriously. If your JS does not work: Read the errors your browser gives you.

[image: $ not defined]

When it works, you have loaded jQuery:

[image: jQuery loaded]

When it doesn't work, you have not:

[image: jQuery not loaded]

---

**If you use a library, make sure you load that library**.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is invalid, as far as I'm aware you cannot do this

```
header{
//css here
    .a{
    //more css here
    }
}
```

you have to do

```
header{
//css
}


header.a{
//css
}
```